# why button cannot move in animation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, uianimation

I want to click `_transitButton` to call `onTransitButtonDidClick` to move `_rightView`.
The problem is the button cannot do as I set `self.transitButton.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 20);`.

### update:

`_transitButton` original frame is `(0,280,30,20)`
the result is, the button move from  the original frame to `(0,0,30,20)`, but quickly move back to original point.
why it went back?

why and how to solve this issue?

```
- (IBAction)onTransitButtonDidClick:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     [_rightView setFrame:CGRectMake(40,0,320,548)];
                     [_transitButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,30,20];
                 }
                 completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: on click you want to move a button in an animation and be able click it AGAIN in the animation which would start the animation over again?

Comment: nope,I just click the button once, as the _rightView has moved in animation which covered the button.

Comment: I dont get ^^ who calls inTransitButtonDidClick .. you said the button should

Comment: It's IBAction. when you click _transitButton, the function is called.

Comment: Just FYI. You really should have a tag here for Objective-C. Really you should have one for Cocoa-Touch too, but at the very least Objective-C. Thanks, and good luck. :)

Comment: thanks buddy. just I think is not tag problem.

Comment: AH now with your update I can follow a bit. @AceLegend is right btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using autolayout in your xib and constraints keep the button in place.
with animation it appears to work because the constraints arent evaluated for animations.

so either turn off AUTOLAYOUT for this xib or modify the appropriate constrains.

(I tried this with a small sample app and that's it.)

Comment: you are right. it's caused by autolayout. and I unchecked it from nib file it okay.